# How to store an arrays within a PersistentVector item?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm attempting the Bucket List Design challenge here:

https://github.com/near-examples/workshop--exploring-assemblyscript-contracts

In the notes it says there is one model `Activity`, and this should include a `PersistentVector` for a list of friends.

My activities are stored as a `PersistentVector`, so this  would mean a nested `PersistentVector` with the `Activity` model - it seems this would not be possible. Am I missing something, or is this maybe designed to create a bit of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s certainly possible to have a `PersistentVector<Activity>`, and inside each activity have a `PersistentVector<string>` with friends. However, using this datastructure, I think you end up with a shared list of friends for all activites (unless you use a unique prefix). If you use `PersistentVector` for your activities, then it’s possible to use a regular list (`string[]`) for your friends to isolate it inside one activity. Otherwise, you would need to store the `PersistentVector` of friends using the id of your activity (maybe as the unique prefix like below)

```
friends: PersistentVector<string> = new PersistentVector<string>(uniqueIdOfActivity);
```

I haven’t tested my hypothesis yet, but as far as I understand, a PersistentVector is just a helper to use the storage

Comment: Thanks for the reply @John.

I've done a test - when using a `PersistentVector` inside another `PersistentVector` it looks like just a reference is saved. e.g.

{
    item: 'item1',
    friends: {
      _elementPrefix: 'item1Friends::',
      _lengthKey: 'item1Friends:len',
      _length: 3
    },
    cost: 1
  }

As you say a unique id would be needed for the prefix - not accounted for in the challenge as the `Activity`'s `item may not be unique. Yep, a string with the friends array items may be more suitable in this case.